# Advice on mariadb replication issue

Tags: database, centos, synchronization, mariadb, replication

I am running mariadb 5.5.2 on two Centos 7.1.1503 bare metal Dell servers. The servers are each 16 months old. They were never rebooted until July 2017. Call the first server salt01 call the second one salt02. salt02 was rebooted first, salt01 was rebooted next.

Since then, have noticed that the db on salt02 is missing entries we see on salt01. Those records co-incide with the reboot; that is, data is missing since then but previous data is present on salt02.

iptables is not running on these two servers.

This appears to be replication issue.

We have two ways to fix:

1. Follow a re-sync procedure that goes like this:

At the master:

```
RESET MASTER;
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /a/path/mysqldump.sql
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

and on slave:

```
STOP SLAVE;
mysql -uroot -p < mysqldump.sql
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',                 
MASTER_LOG_POS=valuefromshowmasterstatus;
START SLAVE;
```

2. Fix replication

Notice this in file /etc/my.cnf

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

on salt02 which is believed to be slave. How critical is this? Could point bind-address to master salt01 and restart mariadb on salt02

Was wondering about thoughts on which way to go here. I'm not a dba. Many thanks for your thoughts? Any questions feel free.

Comment: Welcome to SO - this forum is for programming related questions - you should move it to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ which is db specific.

Comment: Ouch.  That sounds like replaying the replication stream.  Seems like that would lead to duplicates and other messes.